# MongoRuntimeError: Connection pool closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I am seeing my mongoose pool seemingly close before it inserts data as I am getting this error when making a call to my mongoose db in my cloud cluster

```
MongoRuntimeError: Connection pool closed
```

but I am awaiting all of the calls? so I'm unsure why I'm seeing this issue, maybe it has something to do with the way I am defining my client? hopefully someone has some tips or ideas on this

```
export const storeData = async (data) =>{
    const uri = `mongodb+srv://plantmaster:${password}@cluster0.yey8l.mongodb.net/plantstore?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1
      });

        const newPLantData = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
        await client.db("plantstore").collection("plantdata").insertOne(newPLantData, (err, res) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
        })
       
        await client.close();
};
```

I am calling this function on an express post route like so

```
// store data
app.post('/store', async function (req, res) {
 await storeData(req.body);
  res.send('data was stored')
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i was facing the same error, but i fixed it by waiting 1500ms before closing the connection.

```
setTimeout(() => {client.close()}, 1500)
```

Comment: thanks this actually works for me too :) I suppose somewhere down the line the mongo library has some non working async behavior in the library?

Comment: I guess you both are missing an await somewhere?

Comment: This worked for me with a timeout period of 1 ms, which suggests to me it's related to the JS event loop somehow. I have not fallen down that rabbit hole, however.

Comment: It should work fine with mongodb version 4.12.1 without using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example approach

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { email } = req.body;

    if (!email || !email.includes("@")) {
      res.status(422).json({ message: "Entered email is not valid" });
      return;
    }

    const url = <your-mongo-url>
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
    
    const collection = client.db("events").collection("newsletter");

    try {
      await collection.insertOne({ email });
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: "You have successfully signed up to newsletters!",
        email,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error occured" });
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
};

export default handler;
```