# Mongo DB Runtime Error because of connection is closed too early

Tags: mongodb, mern

I had the same issue with the below question, and the answer(adding setTimeout()) worked for me.

[MongoRuntimeError: Connection pool closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155712/mongoruntimeerror-connection-pool-closed)

But I can't find more information about this issue on any other documents, Youtube video, or MongoDB Guide. All of them close the connection without setTimeout function. Am I missing something? or if there is a better way to close the connection. Please advise.

```html
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const url =
    "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.feify.mongodb.net/products_test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    const newProduct = {
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
    };
    const client = new MongoClient(url);

    try {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db();
        const result = db.collection("products").insertOne(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({ message: "Could not store data." });
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        client.close();
    }, 1500);
    res.json(newProduct);
};

const getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {};

exports.createProduct = createProduct;
exports.getProducts = getProducts;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should `await` the `insertOne` function:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const url =
    "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.feify.mongodb.net/products_test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    const newProduct = {
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
    };
    const client = new MongoClient(url);

    try {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db();
        const collection = db.collection("products");
        const result = await collection.insertOne(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({ message: "Could not store data." });
    }

    client.close();
    
    res.json(newProduct);
};

const getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {};

exports.createProduct = createProduct;
exports.getProducts = getProducts;
```